# remove just one link in div section but not the nav menu in the same div

Tags: html, css

I have a CSS problem. A link is within a "main div" and I want it removed. But below is a link section so I cannot do "#main a {display: none}".

The one that says "Skip navigation" is what I want removed. AND, I cannot remove ANYTHING from the HTML (uni assignment)

```
    <div id="menu">
        <a href="#maincontent">Skip navigation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">find usa></li>
        </ul>
```

I have tried all sorts of CSS:

```
menu #maincontent a {display:none;}
menu a {display: none;}
```

and 10 others, but to no avail.

Any help greatly appreciated

Comment: [Use this list for future reference](http://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize--net-16048) :)

Answer (score 1):

Use direct child selector:

```
#menu > a{display:none;} /*hides skip navigation only*/
```

---

This is wrong:

```
menu #maincontent a {display:none;}
menu a {display: none;}
```

I will do like this:

```
#menu a#maincontent {display:none;}
#menu > a {display: none;}
```

---

But since id is unique, you can apply css for that directly:

```
#maincontent{display:none;}
```

Comment: #maincontent is not the id, it's the href attribute

Comment: THANK YOU SO MUCH, C-link Nepal!

#menu > a{display:none;}

solved it. I can't believe i did not think of this myself!

Comment: "Cannot remove anything from html" usually also means can't change the html. I was just pointing that out in case someone tried it and wondered why it didn't work. you didn't mention that they would have to add it as an id

Comment: @Bobo you're absolutely right, but my first point was to use direct child selector, and then other things are as OP coding style is wrong so I just aware that....

Answer (score 0):

You can simply give and id for that `<a>` tag for example #maincontent and do this:

HTML:

```
<div id="menu">
        <a href="#maincontent" id="maincontent">Skip navigation</a>
        <ul>
            <li><a href="#">home</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">project</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">information</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">contakt</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">find usa></li>
        </ul>
```

CSS:

```
#maincontent {
    display:none;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, but that removes a whole bunch of the page.

Answer (score 0):

If you really don't want to change **anything** in the HTML, you can use an attribute selector for the `href`:

```
#menu a[href="#maincontent"] {
    display: none;
}
```

Or event target the `<a>` with a child positioning pseudo selector, such as `:nth-child(n)`, `:first-child`, or `:first-of-type`. But then you'd have to subject them with a direct child selector `>`. Example:

```
#menu > a:first-child {
    display: none;
}
```